# React Material-UI Table how to set "border-spacing" for Table to have separated rows

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I need separate Material-UI Collapsi Table Rows
https://material-ui.com/components/tables/#CollapsibleTable.tsx

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiTable: {
      root: {
        borderCollapse: "separate",
        borderSpacing: "0 10px",
        marginTop: "-10px"
      }
    },
    MuiTableRow: {
      root: {
        borderRadius: 40,
        border: "2px solid",
        backgroundColor: "green",
      },
    },
  },
});
```

To be something like this with spacing in between.
[image: https://codepen.io/jarakramar/pen/dyOyroo]

Best way is by setting the Theme, but Ill be glad for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

It is useless to set borderRadius to MuiTableRow it is needed to use first-child last-child and MuiTableCell.

```
MuiTableCell: {
          root: {
            backgroundColor: "#fff",
            paddingTop: 0,
            paddingBottom: 0,
            paddingLeft: "0.2rem",
            paddingRight: "0.2rem",
            borderBottom: 0,
            overflow: "hidden",
            textOverflow: "ellipsis",
            "&:first-child": {
              borderTopLeftRadius: "0.7rem",
              borderBottomLeftRadius: "0.7rem"
            },
            "&:last-child": {
              borderTopRightRadius: "0.7rem",
              borderBottomRightRadius: "0.7rem"
            }
          }
},
```